# How to get the extension of patch file using powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
if($?)
{
    $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    if($?)
        {
            $historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
        if($?)
        {
            $a = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-
            Object  @{Name="Title";Expression={'"'+$_.Title'"'}}| Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
            if($?)
            {
                $combined=ForEach-Object {$a}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see above code it will give patches names list which is installed in system. I need to filter using `.msu` or `.exe` file types to uninstall.

Comment: Please suggest if you have any idea about this.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: $Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"

$hotfixes = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering | select HotfixID

if($hotfixes -match $PatchID ) {

$TypeCheck = $PatchID | Where {$_.extension -eq $FileType} 

$PatchID = $PatchID.Replace("KB","")

$UninstallString = "cmd.exe /c wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:$PatchID /quiet /norestart"

([WMICLASS]"\\$computername\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create($UninstallString) | out-null

while (@(Get-Process wusa -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count -ne 0) {
Start-Sleep 3

write-output "Sucess"
exit 0

Comment: $hotfixes = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering | select HotfixID
if($?){
if($hotfixes -match $PatchID ) {
if($?){
$TypeCheck = $PatchID | Where {$_.extension -eq $FileType}

 i have used above $_.extension command to filter the file type but its not working..please suggest what are the possibility to filter the patch file types.

Comment: please suggest can we able to filter it ?